# User Assigned Identities with App Service and Azure SQL does that work?

Tags: azure-managed-identity

I am trying to get App Service to connect with Azure Sql database. I can git is nicely work with System Assigned Identities with the same code, but I prefer to use User Assigned Identities (UAI), but I cannot get it work.

Steps which I do:

1. Created a UAI via the portal, name of the UAI "uai-dev-appname-001"
2. At the Identity tab of the Azure App Service I selected 'User Assigned Identity' and selected the UAI made in the previous step.
3. Ran the following SQL CMD

```
CREATE USER [uai-dev-appname-001] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [uai-dev-appname-001]
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [uai-dev-appname-001]
```

4. Set Connectionstring in the ASP.NET to:

   > Data Source=sqlsrv-name-dev-001.database.windows.net; Initial Catalog=sqldb-name-dev-001;
5. Using the following code in mine ASP.NET Core:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection
{
   ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("nameDatabase")
};
AzureServiceTokenProvider provider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var token = provider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
connection.AccessToken = token;
```

6. Deploy to Azure App Service and watched the URL. The result is: error 500.30
7. Looking in the Application Event Log:

   > Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net, Authority: . Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
   >   Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net, Authority: . Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. Received a non-retryable error. MSI ResponseCode: BadRequest, Response: {"StatusCode":400,"Message":"No MSI found for specified ClientId/ResourceId.","CorrelationId":"a68bf757-518a-42e1-85a9-342320d39b5a"}
   >   Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net, Authority: . Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Visual Studio Token provider file not found at "D:\local\LocalAppData.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json"
   >   Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net, Authority: . Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. 'az' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   >   operable program or batch file.

The most interesting part in IMO is:

> Response: {"StatusCode":400,"Message":"No MSI found for specified ClientId/ResourceId.","CorrelationId":"a68bf757-518a-42e1-85a9-342320d39b5a"}

Mine question are:

- Does User Assigned Identies work with Azure SQL?
- If so what do I do wrong?
- Does someone has a working example.

Comment: Even i couldn't get user managed identity connectivity working with AppService. But as per the following link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet, you gotta be mentioning clientid while using user managed identity. Let me know if you manage to crack using this.

Comment: I am not using the REST protocol to obtain the token, but using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication as mentioned in the TIP as Code examples in the article you mention. 

I don't know how I can add clientId to the call with Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication

Answer (score 14, accepted):

User-assigned Managed Identity is supported from version 1.2.1 of Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.

So, please update the version of Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication to the latest.

Then set *AzureServicesAuthConnectionString* in the Appsettings of the AppService to `RunAs=App;AppId={ClientId of user-assigned identity}`

E.g.

```
RunAs=App;AppId=587f16c8-81ed-41c7-b19a-9ded0dbe2ca2
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#running-the-application-using-managed-identity-or-user-assigned-identity).

Once you do these steps, your code should be using user-assigned managed identity.

Comment: Thanx. This works like a charm. Unfortunately not well documented by Microsoft IMO.

Comment: When I set it up in connection string, it does not work (keyword 'runas' not supported), but setting it in variable works perfectly.

Comment: Great, the documentation is vague about this, but this worked for me!