# Azure App Service with User-assigned identity: retrieve clientId in the app?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-identity

I am running an Azure App Service with one User-assigned identity (and no system-managed identity):
[image]

Is there a way inside the app (i.e. my custom code) to retrieve the clientId of the identity? Or do I need to set that in a app setting to be available inside the app?

Question comes from the fact that I want to use this identity to authenticate using an [AzureCredential](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/0ac7147bbd0440e54754a01c8423f2a831d76aae/src/ResourceManagement/ResourceManager/Authentication/AzureCredentialsFactory.cs#L87) and it needs the clientId.

Or is the better way to use [MSI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/0ac7147bbd0440e54754a01c8423f2a831d76aae/src/ResourceManagement/ResourceManager/Authentication/AzureCredentialsFactory.cs#L74) and set the app setting [AzureServicesAuthConnectionString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60403506/1537195)?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at environment variables in an App Service with a User assigned Managed Identity, there is nothing that contains the id.

So you should set the id as an App Setting on the app, and use it.
I definitely recommend that you use AzureCredential as it is the newer one.
The older AzureServiceTokenProvider would not give you any advantage over it anyway.

Comment: thanks! where do you have the info from that AzureCredentials is better? One advantage I still see for the TokenProvider is that is works out of the box with different providers (e.g. CLI, MSI, AAD-joined machine) and tries them all automatically. Is there something like this when using AzureCredentials?

Comment: DefaultAzureCredential does the same :) In fact the newer version supports more providers like VS Code and shared token cache.

Comment: Ohh I just realized you were talking about some other AzureCredential :\ The new one I'm talking about is from the Azure.Identity package.

Comment: are you referring to this? https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity This is yet another lib I believe. Have to try out yet if I can use that instead with the Fluent Management SDK

Comment: If Azure.Identity is not directly usable, it does look like AzureCredentials is not `sealed`, so you could create a new class that inherits from it and gets tokens using DefaultAzureCredential instead.